# How to fix the below issue while creating a derived column in pyspark?

Tags: python-3.x, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to do binning on a particular column in dataframe based on the data given in the dictionary.

Below is the dataframe I used:

df

```
SNo,Name,CScore
1,x,700
2,y,850
3,z,560
4,a,578
5,b,456
6,c,678
```

I have created the below function,it is working fine if I use it seperately.

```
def binning(column,dict):
    finalColumn=[]
    lent = len(column)
    for i in range(lent):
        for j in range(len(list(dict))):
            if( int(column[i]) in range(list(dict)[j][0],list(dict)[j][1])):
                finalColumn.append(dict[list(dict)[j]])
    return finalColumn
```

I have used the above function in the below statement.

```
newDf = df.withColumn("binnedColumn",binning(df.select("CScore").rdd.flatMap(lambda x: x).collect(),{(1,400):'Low',(401,900):'High'}))
```

I am getting the below error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in 
  File "C:\spark_2.4\python\pyspark\sql\dataframe.py", line 1988, in withColumn
    assert isinstance(col, Column), "col should be Column"
AssertionError: col should be Column

Any help to solve this issue will be of great help.Thanks.

Comment: You need to make `binning` into a user defined function (`udf`). Also don't name your variables `dict`. Also calling `collect()` *inside* `withColumn` is going to give you *terrible* performance.You can probably achieve the same result using `when()` and `between()`.

Comment: I have used the udf and renamed the dict variable ,even though it is not working.Any other suggestion ? Thanks..

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48427185/how-to-make-good-reproducible-apache-spark-examples) which includes the exact code you've tried and the full error messages or an explanation of why it's not working. It's also recommended that you also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets start with creating the data:

```
rdd = sc.parallelize([[1,"x",700],[2,"y",850],[3,"z",560],[4,"a",578],[5,"b",456],[6,"c",678]])
df = rdd.toDF(["SNo","Name","CScore"])
>>> df.show()
+---+----+------+
|SNo|Name|CScore|
+---+----+------+
|  1|   x|   700|
|  2|   y|   850|
|  3|   z|   560|
|  4|   a|   578|
|  5|   b|   456|
|  6|   c|   678|
+---+----+------+
```

if your final goal is to provide a binning_dictionary like your example do, to find the corresponding categorical value.
udf is the solution.

the following is your normal function.

```
bin_lookup = {(1,400):'Low',(401,900):'High'}
def binning(value, lookup_dict=bin_lookup):
    for key in lookup_dict.keys():
        if key[0] <= value <= key[1]:
             return lookup_dict[key]
```

to register as a udf and run it via dataframe:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf
from pyspark.sql.types import StringType

binning_udf = udf(binning, StringType())
>>> df.withColumn("binnedColumn", binning_udf("CScore")).show()
+---+----+------+------------+
|SNo|Name|CScore|binnedColumn|
+---+----+------+------------+
|  1|   x|   700|        High|
|  2|   y|   850|        High|
|  3|   z|   560|        High|
|  4|   a|   578|        High|
|  5|   b|   456|        High|
|  6|   c|   678|        High|
+---+----+------+------------+
```

directly apply to rdd:

```
>>> rdd.map(lambda row: binning(row[-1], bin_lookup)).collect()
['High', 'High', 'High', 'High', 'High', 'High']
```